# Hastable in C#: Using the same key multiple times

Tags: c#, hashtable

I fetch multiple records with the same id and I want to store them in a `Hashtable` in C#. I'm using the id as the key in the `Hashtable`, and the value is the object itself. It throws an exception because the same key is added again. Is there a way to fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
Hashtable localItemsIndex = new Hashtable();            
foreach (TzThing thing in localThingz)
         localItemsIndex.Add(thing.Id, thing);
```

Thanks in advance
jennie

Comment: Do you *have* to use the old non-generic collections, or are you happy for us to propose solutions based on .NET 2 and higher? What about LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you should use `Dictionary<Id,List<TzThing>>` to store multiple values for one key

```
public void Add(YourIdType key,TzThing thing )
{
   if(dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
   {
      dictionary[key].Add(thing);
   }
   else
   {
      dictionary.Add(key,new List<TzThing> {thing});
   }
}
```

Comment: Can u please brief me how to store in dictionary for same key

Answer (score 1):

The hashtable key must be unique: you can't add the same key twice into it. You may use List or HashSet where T is the key-value pair of your class (or use the .net KeyValuePair class) or the Dictionary class where V the list or set but you'll still need to manage the duplicate key insertion manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many things to go with the same key, put your things in a List.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use HashTable for this. It only accepts unique keys. Otherwise you need to use `List<T>` with `KeyValuePair<key,value>` class.